# Calculating combinations with duplicated values and stacks that hold more than one value

Tags: combinations, permutation, calculated-columns

Brace yourself. Given a set of number with various values repeated (i.e. 1,2,2,2,3,4,5,5,6,7,7) and special slots that can hold an infinite amount of values, how would one calculate the possible combinations where each value is distributed into one of the slots once and only once? Another restriction is that each slot has to have at least one value. The final restriction is that value combinations within a single slot cannot be repeated within a single trial. For instance:

1 | 2,7 | 2,3,4,5 | 2,7 | 6

This would be illegal because "2,7" is repeated within a single set (meaning one combination). The numbers above act as a single combination, or one trial. To press the return key would initialize a second trial (combination), in which "2,7" could be repeated with no error. Whereas:

1,2 | 2,2,3,4| 5,5,6 | 7,7

and

1,2 | 2,2,3| 5,5,6 | 4,7,7

would be legal because "5,5,6" is only repeated in a separate trial. Above are two separate combinations (two trials). "5,5,6" is, indeed, repeated but the repetition clause only applies and is illegal when  repetition is present within one combination.

I'm not sure how to apply basic combination arithmetic to this problem or even if basic formulas could apply. How would this problem be calculated? Help.

Comment: can you please provide sample input and output. I could not understand the whole problem

Comment: you say each value should be distributed into one of the slots once and only once, then in the example you say that 5,5,6 is legal. This is confusing, please improve the problem statement.

Comment: It seems that you want to partition a MULTISET into N multisets, with the additional constraint that none of these multisets are identical. You want to have all the possible partitions. Without the additional constraint, the problem is already NP-hard because the number of possible partitions has factorial growth. I dont see other possibility than brute force enumeration.